# USB Host controller not working

Tags: windows-8, laptop, usb, hardware-failure

My usb ports were acting very weird and I found some guides on internet, so obviously I followed the guides.

I've found 5 guides telling me to uninstall the host controllers, then the host controllers would be automatically installed again at boot up and now this is showing me next to all the host:

[image]

So the next step would be to check if the USB ports would work normally again. So I tried and the USB ports didn't work anymore. Like the device connected to the usb port would normally light up. Now it doesn't even light up anymore. How should I fix the USB host controller?

Answer (score 0):

The drivers do not always reinstall when you do that. You'll need to install the drivers for your USB controller(s). You can get those from the manufacturer's website.